# Use tab and shift-tab to navigate out of a wxStyledTextCtrl within a wxPanel

Tags: wxwidgets

I am attempting to make a wxWidgets application, specifically poEdit, more accessible using the keyboard. There is a wxPanel that contains three controls; a combo box, a button, and a read only wxStyledTextCtrl. The problem is that once focus gets into the wxStyledTextCtrl it is impossible to move back to the other controls using the keyboard. I want to be able to tab out of the wxStyledTextCtrl back to the combo box. Thus far I have tried calling SetTabIndents(false) but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I am going to end up sub classing the wxStyledTextCtrl class and customizing the WM_GETDLGCODE message. At least that is what the article *Those who do not understand the dialog manager are doomed to reimplement it, badly* found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/06/27/3555596.aspx implies I will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my own question. I did end up sub classing the wxStyledTextCtrl class and overriding the MSWWindowProc function to customize the processing of the WM_GETDLGCODE message to clear the DLGC_WANTALLKEYS and DLGC_WANTTAB bits. The code I used is as follows.

The code I used to do this is as follows.

```
<myStc.h>
#include <wx/stc/stc.h>

class myWxStyledTextCtrl : public wxStyledTextCtrl
{
public:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS(myWxStyledTextCtrl);
    myWxStyledTextCtrl(
        wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = 0,
        const wxString& name = wxSTCNameStr);
    myWxStyledTextCtrl();
    void SetUseTabToNavigate(bool useTabToNavigate);

#ifdef __WXMSW__
    // special Windows message handling
    virtual WXLRESULT MSWWindowProc(
        WXUINT nMsg, WXWPARAM wParam, WXLPARAM lParam);
#endif

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
private:
    bool m_useTabToNavigate;
};
</myStc.h>

<myStc.cpp>
#include "myStc.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS(myWxStyledTextCtrl, wxStyledTextCtrl);
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(myWxStyledTextCtrl, wxStyledTextCtrl)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

myWxStyledTextCtrl::myWxStyledTextCtrl(
    wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id /*= wxID_ANY*/,
    const wxPoint& pos /*= wxDefaultPosition*/,
    const wxSize& size /*= wxDefaultSize*/, long style /*= 0*/,
    const wxString& name /*= wxSTCNameStr*/) :
    wxStyledTextCtrl(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
{
    m_useTabToNavigate = false;
}

myWxStyledTextCtrl::myWxStyledTextCtrl() :
    wxStyledTextCtrl()
{
    m_useTabToNavigate = false;
}

void myWxStyledTextCtrl::SetUseTabToNavigate(bool useTabToNavigate)
{
    m_useTabToNavigate = useTabToNavigate;
}

#ifdef __WXMSW__
WXLRESULT myWxStyledTextCtrl::MSWWindowProc(
    WXUINT nMsg, WXWPARAM wParam, WXLPARAM lParam)
{
    WXLRESULT ret = wxStyledTextCtrl::MSWWindowProc(nMsg, wParam, lParam);
    if (!m_useTabToNavigate)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    if (nMsg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
    {
        ret &= ~(DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTTAB);
    }
    return ret;
}
#endif
</myStc.cpp>
```

I may figure out a solution that will work for other operating systems at some point in the future.